# Program that can compile a python file from an alredy compiled python file

Tags: python, compilation, exe

I'm searching a way to compile a python file into an exe from an alredy compiled python file.

For example:
I have `main_script.py`, I used PyInstaller to convert it into `main_script.exe`

Into `main_script.exe` there is a part of code that **convert** some hardcoded lines of python into a new exe (or maybe even creating a python file, converting it and then deleting the python file).

Now when I start `main_script.exe` I need to have `new_exe.exe` and `another_exe.exe` in my cwd (Current Working Directory).

I searched a lot but I didn't found anything useful, can someone help me? Thanks

Comment: You can use PyInstaller in your program, so just write it directly into your original script before compiling.

Comment: @Laif Can you please be more specific? I can't understand what you are saying to me

Comment: In the same way that you manually used pyinstallerto create your first exe, you can script it to do that automatically in python.

Comment: @Laif I use PyInstaller in the commandline, not in scripts. Using the os.system('pyinstaller ...') won't work because PyInstaller doesn't create fake modules for PyInstaller since it's not imported as a regular module

Comment: It can be used inside python. Check out [this page](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/usage.html) for more info